# What is the alternate form of $\,\arcsin x\,?$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, inverse-function

$\sin x$ can be expressed as

$$\frac{e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$$

through transformations using Euler's formula. I am wondering if $\arcsin x$ has an equivalent, perhaps in logarithms.

Can we find the inverse of the above equation?

Comment: You'll find it on Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions#Logarithmic_forms.

Comment: Ahhh I didn't see it. I tried finding it using Wolfram Alpha and they didn't have it. Thanks

Comment: WolframAlpha is always a good place to start.

Answer (score 8):

Notice that

$$x=\sin(\arcsin(x))=\frac{e^{i\arcsin(x)}-e^{-i\arcsin(x)}}{2i}$$

Multiply both sides by $u=e^{i\arcsin(x)}$ to get

$$xu=\frac1{2i}u^2-\frac1{2i}$$

Which is a quadratic in $u$.  Solving for $u$ can be done with the quadratic formula, and then $\arcsin(x)$ may be found with logarithms.

The end result is

$$\arcsin(x)=\frac1i\ln\left(ix\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\right)$$

Notice the quadratic formula inside the logarithm?

Comment: Very interesting method! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: @tphilli :D  Glad to hear!  Hope it satisfies you.

Answer (score 2):

You can write it as

$$\arcsin(x) = \int \limits_0^x \frac{dt}{\sqrt{1 - t^2}} $$

which has a certain (far fetched) similarity to the logarithm:

$$\log(x) =  \int_1^x \frac 1tdt$$

Comment: I imagine the OP was looking towards a complex representation, one capable of taking things like $\arcsin(i)$.

Comment: Yes now that I see the other answers I think so too, but without that inspiration this was what I could come up with.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is how the inverse $\sin$ function is expressed via the $\log$ function:
$$
\arcsin(x) = -i \log(i x + \sqrt{1 - x^2})
$$

Interesting counterparts to this are the following expressions of $\log(x)$:
$$
\log(x) = i \arcsin\left({1 + x^2\over2 x}\right) - {\pi i\over2}  \ \ \ \qquad\mbox{ for }  x\ge1, \qquad
$$
$$
\log(x) = - i \arcsin\left({1 + x^2\over2 x}\right) + {\pi i\over2} \qquad\mbox{ for } 0<x\le1.
$$

Comment: Or more generally, one should split it up over $|x|>1$ and $|x|<1$.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $\arcsin x$ is the (one of the) solution(s) of $$\frac{e^{iy}-e^{-iy}}{2i}=x$$ and if $e^{iy}-e^{-iy}=2ix$, then $$ y=\arcsin(x) = -i\log\left(ix\pm\sqrt{1-x^2}\right). $$

Comment: How exactly do you get from exp(iy)−exp(−iy)=2ix to the last step?

Comment: @tphilli You should see my answer for that.

Comment: @tphilli: set $e^{iy}=w$, solve the equation $w-\frac{1}{w}=2ix$ with respect to $w$, then consider that $y=\frac{\log w}{i}$.

Answer (score 1):

$y = \sin x = \frac {e^{ix} - e^{-ix}}{2i}$

$x = \arcsin y$

So we just need to solve for $x.$

It will be a little bit easier if we do this substitution.
$e^{ix} = z$

$2iy = z - \frac 1z\\
z^2 - 2iyz -1 = 0$

Apply the quadratic formula

$z= iy \pm \sqrt {1-y^2}$

One solution equals $z$ the other solution equals $\frac 1z$ pick one.  And lets reverse the substitution.

$e^{ix} = iy + \sqrt {1-y^2}\\
x = -i \ln (iy + \sqrt {1-y^2})$