# Why is $2i\ln(-i)=\pi$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, logarithms, inverse-function, pi

So I always wanted to make my own approximation for pi. I thought of using trigonometric functions to help me start, so I decided to use arccosine. I put $\cos^{-1}(x) = \pi $ in a calculator to solve for $x$. The [calculator](https://math24.pro/transcendental_equation) has a section called "alternate form" where they change the equation a bit. So they gave me this $$\frac{\pi}{2} + i\ln(\sqrt{1-x^2}+ix) = \pi$$ Substituting $-1$ for $x$:$$\frac{\pi}{2}+i\ln(-i)=\pi$$ Then I combine the first and second terms on the left side to get $2i\ln(-i)$. But I don't know how the first equation even exists. How did the calculator come up with this? Or was that first equation is already well-known?

Comment: Check https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2077674/756975

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are referring to the principal complex branch of the logarithm. Then if $z=re^{i\theta}$, we have
$$
\ln(z)=\ln r + i Arg(z).
$$
In this case, $z=-i$ so $Arg(z)=-\frac{\pi}{2}$.

However, the identity breaks down for different branches.

Comment: What is $Arg(z)$? I've seen it many times.

Comment: @KamalSaleh The argument of a complex number $z$ (the angle it forms)

Comment: @TheBestMagician Okay thanks! I wonder how $Arg(z)$ is in the $\ln$ of a complex number...

Comment: @KamalSaleh It's because $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta=Arg(z)$

Comment: @TheBestMagician So that's why $\theta$ was used (since, as you know, it's used for angles).

Comment: in this case what's $r$?

Comment: @KamalSaleh: To be honest, if you don't even know polar coordinates on the complex plane, that's a much more pressing thing to learn than this identity, which is really a trivial result of knowing basics about complex numbers.

Comment: I thought $r$ was some variable. I forgot momentarily that $r$ is the distance from the origin in the polar coordinate system.

Answer (score 0):

For a complex number $z = r e^{i \theta}$,
$$
\ln \left(z\right) = \ln r + i\left(\theta + 2n\pi\right), n \in {\mathbb Z}
$$
See [this link](https://complex-analysis.com/content/logarithmic_function.html) for an explanation.

With [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula) you should be able to see that $-i = e^{-i \pi/2}$.

For $z = -i = e^{-i \pi/2}$, $r = 1$ and $\theta = -\pi/2$, so
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln \left(-i\right) &=& \ln \left(1\right) + i\left(-\frac{\pi}{2} + 2n\pi\right) \\ &=& i \pi \left(-\frac{1}{2} + 2n\right) \\ &=& ..., -\frac{9\pi i}{2}, -\frac{5\pi i}{2}, -\frac{\pi i}{2}, \frac{3\pi i}{2}, \frac{7\pi i}{2}, ...
\end{eqnarray}
$$

To derive your first equation, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4270772/35995), equation 29 [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.413.5729&rep=rep1&type=pdf), or the Inverse Trigonometric Functions section [here](http://www.milefoot.com/math/complex/functionsofi.htm).

Comment: So I substitute one of the numbers in the last list into my original problem and then I'll easily solve for it, right?

Comment: @KamalSaleh I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. Do you want to understand where your first equation comes from?

Comment: Yes that's my question. Sorry for being vague.

Comment: @KamalSaleh I updated my answer with a few links that should be helpful.